# ReactJS Sass, without webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Preface: I can't use webpack. It breaks too much of my AWS stuff and I'm too frustrated finding ever more problems. I wish I could use the convenience of webpack but I stopped using it and AWS now works. Now its all watchify and babel.

Can I use CSS/Sass without using Webpack (as mentioned) or import CSS Modules, PostCSS etc?

Issue: I can link a css file, pass in the classes to my component and it all renders out proper div / class syntax, but (I assume) the virtual DOM just doesnt load it. How can I get around this?

[Edited as I got a down-vote, just to be safe.]

Answer (score -1):

You can just run gulp, and [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass). That compiles a .css file and you can just manually include that file in the `<head>` of your file. Try there are dozens of tutorials on Google like [this](http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-gulp-and-sass/) one

Comment: I can create the css but it isn't 'rendered' in react. That's my issue.

Comment: Just add an oldfashion `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path_to_your/style.css">` in your `<head>` in your index.html. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't do anything? No errors as well? Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: As above, I can't use webpack

Comment: Sorry, i meant gulp config. 

So you have a fully valid css file and placed the right css file in the head of your .html? No browsers errors? Because React just renders html with javascript. It doesn't matter what or when gets rendered. CSS always applies to whatever DOM that gets injected into the browser. Virtual or not.

Comment: Not even that. just running watchify and babel from the package start script. Real barebones.

Comment: The css is found and linked and only has the most basic class to test, but no. Just doesnt render. I rewrite it in reacts way and works fine. I just assumed it was because react elements were loading after the head but that doesnt seem right.

Comment: I fixed it by updating the head post load. I've seen examples of your method working though. Thanks for your help @Sam Pakvis